# How to update a previous run into MLFlow?

Tags: logging, data-science, mlflow

I would like to update previous runs done with MLFlow, ie. changing/updating a parameter value to accommodate a change in the implementation. Typical uses cases:

- Log runs using a parameter A, and much later, log parameters A and B. It would be useful to update the value of parameter B of previous runs using its default value.
- "Specialize" a parameter. Implement a model using a boolean flag as a parameter. Update the implementation to take a string instead. Now we need to update the values of the parameter for the previous runs so that it stays consistent with the new behavior.
- Correct a wrong parameter value loggued in the previous runs.

It is not always easy to trash the whole experiment as I need to keep the previous runs for statistical purpose. I would like also not to generate new experiments just for a single new parameter, to keep a single database of runs.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Did you have error `INVALID_PARAMETER_VALUE` when trying to update an existing parameter value?

Comment: @panc I don't remember exactly, but it's probable

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To add or correct a parameter, metric or artifact of an existing run, pass run_id instead of experiment_id to mlflow.start_run function

```
with mlflow.start_run(run_id="your_run_id") as run:
    mlflow.log_param("p1","your_corrected_value")
    mlflow.log_metric("m1",42.0) # your corrected metrics
    mlflow.log_artifact("data_sample.html") # your corrected artifact file
```

You can correct, add to, or delete any MLflow run any time after it is complete. Get the run_id either from the UI or by using [mlflow.search_runs](https://www.mlflow.org/docs/latest/python_api/mlflow.html#mlflow.search_runs).

Source: https://towardsdatascience.com/5-tips-for-mlflow-experiment-tracking-c70ae117b03f

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me on MLflow 1.13.1. When I tried to correct an existing parameter, it issues the error `RestException: INVALID_PARAMETER_VALUE: Changing param values is not allowed. Param with key='test_rmse' was already logged with value='3.061878' for run ID='fe03293adb7e4c79a716c11fc938c044'. Attempted logging new value '0'.`

Comment: @panc same issue here. Did you find a solution ?

Comment: @cyberjoac Not yet. I started a thread on Github https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/issues/3999, but no reply yet.

Answer (score 1):

MLflow API does not support updating an existing parameter value, see [this](https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/issues/3999).

However, there are backdoors you can use to achieve the goal of rewriting an existing parameter's value. But use with caution.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can't update it but there is another solution which is getting the run, edit the value that you want, and then log the run as a whole new run.

```
import mlflow 
import os 
os.environ["MLFLOW_EXPERIMENT_NAME"] = "REPLACE_YOUR_EXPERIEMNTE_NAME"

original_run_id = 'REPLACE_YOUR_RUN_ID'
original_run = mlflow.get_run(original_run_id)
original_run_name = original_run.data.tags.get('mlflow.runName')

with mlflow.start_run(run_name=original_run_name) as new_run:
    for key, value in original_run.data.params.items():
        if key == 'REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_KEY':
            new_value = REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_VALUE
            mlflow.log_param(key, new_value)
        else:
            mlflow.log_param(key, value)

    for key, value in original_run.data.metrics.items():
        mlflow.log_metric(key, value)
```

setting the epxeriemnt name and run name are optional, the run_id should grab the exact run that you want. But setting the run name will help you create a name the same as before. This snippet currently updates a param, you can change it to update a metric.