# How to add more metrics to a finished MLflow run?

Tags: python, databricks, mlflow

Once an MLflow run is finished, external scripts can access its parameters and metrics using python `mlflow` client and `mlflow.get_run(run_id)` method, but the `Run` object returned by `get_run` seems to be read-only.

Specifically, `.log_param` `.log_metric`, or `.log_artifact` cannot be used on the object returned by `get_run`, raising errors like these:

```
AttributeError: 'Run' object has no attribute 'log_param'
```

If we attempt to run any of the `.log_*` methods on `mlflow`, it would log them into to a new run  with auto-generated run ID in the `Default` experiment.

Example:

```
final_model_mlflow_run = mlflow.get_run(final_model_mlflow_run_id)

with mlflow.ActiveRun(run=final_model_mlflow_run) as myrun:    
    
    # this read operation uses correct run
    run_id = myrun.info.run_id
    print(run_id)
    
    # this write operation writes to a new run 
    # (with auto-generated random run ID) 
    # in the "Default" experiment (with exp. ID of 0)
    mlflow.log_param("test3", "This is a test")
```

Note that the above problem exists regardless of the `Run` status (`.info.status` can be both "FINISHED" or "RUNNING", without making any difference).

I wonder if this read-only behavior is by design (given that immutable modeling runs improve experiments reproducibility)? I can appreciate that, but it also goes against code modularity if everything has to be done within a single monolith like the `with mlflow.start_run()` context...

Comment: Does the answer from here help you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/65110356/7132596

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it was pointed out to me by [Hans Bambel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7132596/hans-bambel) and as it is documented [here](https://www.mlflow.org/docs/latest/python_api/mlflow.html#mlflow.start_run) `mlflow.start_run` (in contrast to `mlflow.ActiveRun`) accepts the `run_id` parameter of an existing run.

Here's an example tested to work in v1.13 through v1.19 - as you see one can even overwrite an existing metric to correct a mistake:

```
with mlflow.start_run(run_id=final_model_mlflow_run_id):
    
    # print(mlflow.active_run().info)
    
    mlflow.log_param("start_run_test", "This is a test")
    mlflow.log_metric("start_run_test", 1.23)
    mlflow.log_metric("start_run_test", 1.33)
    mlflow.log_artifact("/home/jovyan/_tmp/formula-features-20201103.json", "start_run_test")
```

Comment: We are currently running the same version (v1.19) of `mlflow` and it works in dozens of modeling runs in multiple monitoring pipelines... If you have a Github account please move the bug report there (but they are rather slow to respond:)

Comment: Tested to work also in the latest `mlflow==2.10.0`.

Answer (score 0):

This question can be divided into two

- modifying an existing param/metric/log in previous run.

For instance:

```
old: mlflow.log_metric("accuracy", 0.85)

new: mlflow.log_metric("accuracy", 0.90)
```

- adding new param/metric/log to previous run

For instance:

```
old: mlflow.log_metric("accuracy", 0.85)

new: mlflow.log_metric("dropout", 0.05)
```

In the previous version of mlflow v1.13 - v1.19, you can do both, that is modify params in previous run, and add new params to previous ran. You need need the run_id for that previous run to do that

```
# initialize mlflow client 
mlflow.set_tracking_uri(track_uri)
mlflow.set_experiment(experiment_name) 


# get run_id with run name 
run_object = mlflow.search_runs(filter_string=f"attributes.run_name = '{run_name}'")
                
run_id = run_object["run_id"]

# start previous run with run_id
with mlflow.start_run(run_id=run_id):
    
# print(mlflow.active_run().info)
    
    # add new param
    mlflow.log_param("accuracy", 0.90)
    mlflow.log_param("droupout", 0.05)
```

This code work for both cases if you have between v1.13 - v1.19 version of mlflow. `mlflow.log_param("accuracy", 0.90)` will fail if your version is more recent than v.1.19. You will get the error "mlflow.exceptions.RestException: INVALID_PARAMETER_VALUE: Changing param values is not allowed." This [github issue](https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/issues/3999) explains why the feature was depreciated.

Adding new params `mlflow.log_param("dropout", 0.05)` to previous run will work for all versions.

Comment: I've been using this method in v1.26.1 to update multiple existing historical runs using the official `mlflow.log_*` functions. Maybe something else has changed in versions newer than 1.19? Are you sure you are properly connecting to the API server, and effectively selecting the proper experiment and run?