# Logging to the very same mlflow run across multiple scripts

Tags: python, mlflow

I have separate preprocessing and training Python scripts. I would like to track my experiments using [mlflow](https://www.mlflow.org/docs/latest/python_api/mlflow.html).
Because my scripts are separate, I am using a Powershell script (think of it as a shell script, but on Windows) to trigger the Python scripts with the same configuration and to make sure that all the scripts operate with the same parameters and data.

How can I track across scripts into the same *mlflow* run?

I am passing the same experiment name to the scripts. To make sure the same run is picked up, I thought to generate a (16 bit hex) run ID in my Powershell script and pass it to all the Python scripts.
This doesn't work as when a run ID is given to `mlflow_start_run()`, *mlflow* expects that run ID to already exist and it fails with `mlflow.exceptions.MlflowException: Run 'dfa31595f0b84a1e0d1343eedc81ee75' not found`.

If I pass a run name, each of the scripts gets logged to a different run anyways (which is expected).

I cannot use `mlflow.last_active_run()` in subsequent scripts, because I need to preserve the ability to run and track/log each script separately.

Comment: This might be helpful to you: [How to update a previous run into MLFlow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64209196/how-to-update-a-previous-run-into-mlflow)